# adding a variable to an array in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, handsontable

I am trying to use a variable that is defined in my .ts file to an array for populating a handsontable but can not get the value

the variable has a value as I have logged to the console

```
console.log("t1 title " ,this.t1Title);
```

I added the string t to see some output but the variable this.t1Title does not work

```
settingsObj: Handsontable.GridSettings = {
    data: [{id: 1, name: ('t'+ this.t1Title)},
           {id: 2, name: 'me'},
           {id: 3, name: 'me' }
    ],
```

if i hard code the string t1Title then the variable works.
I am getting the variable from a service in the  ngOnInit() and assigning like this:

```
    this.t1Title = tAccount['t1Title'];
        console.log("t1 title " ,this.t1Title);
```

I get no value in the Handsontable when i use:

data: [{id: 1, name: this.t1Title},{id: 2, name: 'me'},{id: 3, name: 'me' }],

Comment: How does it not work? I just tried similar code in my application and it worked as expected. Could you provide more information on how it does not work (is it undefined?) and more context where the above shown code is defined?

Comment: Could you add the code where you are doing that to the question (since code in the comments aren't formatted very well.) I would guess based on the information so far that there is an issue with *where* the code is being executed.

Comment: You must create the settingsObj in the subscribe function. Other idea is always in your subscribe function write: this.settingsObj[0].name='t'+this.t1Title

Comment: when i set the settingsObj in ngOnInit() like this

Comment: 'this.settingsObj['data'] =  [{ id: 1, name: 'me' }, { id: 2, name: 'me' }, { id: 3, name: 'me' }]'

Comment: i can see everything but if i use a variable like this:

Comment: this.settingsObj['data'] =  [{ id: 1, name: this.t1Title }, { id: 2, name: 'me' }, { id: 3, name: 'me' }]

Comment: then i cant see a value for this.t1Title even though i know there is a value because i have logged it to the console.

Comment: If you could possibly add a CodePen that reproduces your error, it would be much easier to help you discover the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your service is returning the value of `this.t1Title` asynchronously, possibly through an Observable.

So, when the following code runs:

```
settingsObj: Handsontable.GridSettings = {
    data: [{id: 1, name: ('t'+ this.t1Title)},
           {id: 2, name: 'me'},
           {id: 3, name: 'me' }
    ],
```

the value of `this.t1Title` hasn't yet been populated.

Hence, you need to make sure to only run that code after the Service has actually returned the value. If you are using an Observable, this would be in the `subscribe` function.

Comment: i do set the variable in the ngOnInit():

Comment: `
ngOnInit() {
        const id = "1";
      if (id) {
        this.tAccountService.get(id).subscribe((tAccount: any) => {
          if (tAccount) {
            console.log("we have a t account " ,tAccount);
            this.tAccount = tAccount;
            this.t1Title = tAccount['t1Title'];
            console.log("t1 title " ,this.t1Title);`

Comment: i have tried to set the handsontable after the above is ran but i get an error. my understanding is that the ngOnInit will run first.